# How to open a parent of parent page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I am writing a C#, say a, code to display some information from data base.
and sending that information to an excel sheet.
For excel sheet i have return the script in another page. 
If there is no record in the data source it should come back to the main page i.e. to page a.
How can i handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (RecordCount == 0)
{
    Response.Redirect("a.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your admins are doing URL rewriting you may have to pay attention where to redirect. So you may have to do the Redirect(..) relative to your application URL. [Here's](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/269.aspx) a good post which gives some insight in how to do that.